# How do I patch enumerables with System.Web.Http.OData.Delta?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

Trying to make use of [System.Web.Http.OData.Delta](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/08/15/odata-support-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) to implement [PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) methods in ASP.NET Web API services, but it seems unable to apply changes to properties of type `IEnumerable<T>`. I'm using the latest Git revision of Delta (2012.2-rc-76-g8a73abe). Has anyone been able to make this work?

Consider this data type, which it should be possible to update in a PATCH request to the Web API service:

```
public class Person
{
    HashSet<int> _friends = new HashSet<int>();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Friends
    {
        get { return _friends; }
        set
        {
            _friends = value != null ? new HashSet<int>(value) : new HashSet<int>();
        }
    }

    public Person(int id, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        Id = id;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public Person()
    {
    }
}
```

This Web API method implements patching of a Person through `Delta<Person>`:

```
public void Patch(int id, Delta<Person> delta)
{
    var person = _persons.Single(p => p.Id == id);
    delta.Patch(person);
}
```

If I send a PATCH request with the following JSON to the service, the person's `Friends` property should be updated, but alas it doesn't happen:

```
{"Friends": [1]}
```

The crux of the matter is really how to make Delta update `Friends` with this data. See also the [discussion at CodePlex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/429382).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem likely is that Deta will try to assign JSON's `JArray` to your `Hashset<int>`

If you are using it against JsonMEdiaTypeFormatter and you internalized the Delta code (meaning you can modify it), you'd have to do something like this (this is rough, but works):

Inside,  `bool TrySetPropertyValue(string name, object value)` of `Delta<T>`, where it returns false:

```
        if (value != null && !cacheHit.Property.PropertyType.IsPrimitive && !isGuid && !cacheHit.Property.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
        {
           return false;
        }
```

Change to:

```
var valueType = value.GetType();
var propertyType = cacheHit.Property.PropertyType;
if (value != null && !propertyType.IsPrimitive && !propertyType.IsAssignableFrom(valueType))
{
    var array = value as JArray;
    if (array == null)
        return false;

    var underlyingType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault() ??
        propertyType.GetElementType();
    if (underlyingType == typeof(string))
    {
        var a = array.ToObject<IEnumerable<string>>();
        value = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType, a);
    }
    else if (underlyingType == typeof(int))
    {
        var a = array.ToObject<IEnumerable<int>>();
        value = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType, a);
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

This will only work with collections of `int` or `string` but hopefully nudges you into a good direction.

For example, now your model can have:

```
public class Team {
        public HashSet<string> PlayerIds { get; set; }
        public List<int> CoachIds { get; set; }
    }
```

And you'd be able to successfully update them.

Comment: Thanks, you made my day (again)! I had to change your code significantly though to make it work.

Comment: thanks, well, I typed this without testing directly in here :)

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `TrySetPropertyValue` method of the [Delta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.delta(v=vs.118).aspx) class and make use of [JArray](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) class:

```
public sealed class DeltaWithCollectionsSupport<T> : Delta<T> where T : class
{
    public override bool TrySetPropertyValue(string name, object value)
    {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(name);

        return propertyInfo != null && value is JArray array
            ? base.TrySetPropertyValue(name, array.ToObject(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
            : base.TrySetPropertyValue(name, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ODataMediaTypeFormatter, this should be working. There are a couple of caveats to mention though. 
1) your collections have to be settable.
2) the entire collection is replaced. you cannot remove/add individual elements.

Also, there is an issue tracking item 1 - ['670 -Delta should support non-settable collections.'](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/670)

Comment: No, I'm using the JsonMediaTypeFormatter I guess, whatever's default in Web API as I've only plugged Delta in directly without making any other changes. Are there any particular caveats to making use of ODataMediaTypeFormatter? Does it change my API in any particular way?

Comment: Where can I find information on using ODataMediaTypeFormatter as opposed to JsonMediaTypeFormatter?

Comment: Alex James [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2012/12/07/odata-in-webapi-rc-release.aspx) has really good information for using odata with webapi.

Comment: I've read that blog post, it doesn't really enlighten me as to only implement partial updates (PATCH) rather than OData in full.