# How do i patch enumerables with Odata.Delta with Webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I´m trying to use System.Web.Http.OData.Delta to implement PATCH methods in ASP.NET Web API services, but it seems unable to apply changes to properties of type IEnumerable.

This is my code:

```
public class Person
{
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IList<Document> AdditionalDocuments { get; set; }

        public HomeAddress HomeAddress { get; set; }
}


public class HomeAddress
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The patch is implemented like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
public void Patch(string id, Delta<Person> delta)
{
    var person = personRepository.GetById(id)
    delta.Patch(person);
}
```

My problem is that when i patch the informations, the HomeAddress and the AdditionalDocuments are being ignored. I found another article([How do I patch enumerables with System.Web.Http.OData.Delta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294136/how-do-i-patch-enumerables-with-system-web-http-odata-delta)) here, but i couldn´t implement the solution because i didn´t know how to internalize the Delta code. May someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Delta was designed to work with only the OData formatter. There is a [bug](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/777) open to make it work with json.net formatter.