# WebApi Put how to tell not specified properties from specified properties set to null?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

Here is the scenario. There is an web api put call to change an object in sql server database. We want only to change the fields on the database object if they were explicitly specified on webapi call json. For example:

```
{ "Name":"newName", "Colour":null }
```

That should change the Name field to "newName" and "Colour" field to null. As opposed to this json:

```
{ "Name":"newName" }
```

that should only change the Name field, leaving the old Colour value intact.

What is a good way with WebApi to detect whether a property was passed or not?

If I define my method like this:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("/item/{id}")]
public void ChangeItem(int id, Item item)
{
    ...
}
```

`item.Colour` will be null in either case. Note, that I'm working with a variety of data types here and property `Colour` in the example could be `int`, `string`, `DateTime`, `Guid`, etc.

I understand that I can get the raw json with `[FromBody]` attribute and then parse it myself, but it seems that the default binder is already doing most of the work (including validation), so I would be curious how I could reuse it, but also achieve what I want. What is the easiest way?

**Update**:

I'd like to clarify that mine is an "occasionally connected" scenario. That is, the devices that are using the API are out of network coverage most of the time, and they sync using the API from time to time.

Practically this means that most of the data that is needed to sync are aggregated into zero or one "push updates to server" call followed by "get latest state from server" call. With Sql Server and EF in the back-end that leads to several different (and sometimes unrelated) entities are contained within single json. Eg:

```
class TaskData
{ 
    public IList<User> AssignedUsers {get; set;} 
    public IList<Product> Products {get; set;} 
    public Task Task {get; set}
}
```

Also the model classes that are used to generate json for GET calls are separate from EF Entites, as the database schema does not exactly match the API object model.

Comment: To be honest, put is idempotent. You'd need _patch_...

Comment: @AndreiV, yeah, yeah. Let's not argue about what is pure rest and what is not =)

Comment: I don't like it either... As a workaround, you could require a list of _changing properties_ as an additional parameter.

Comment: @AndreiV yep. That's what it is now. Still very awkard. My api consumer is asking me why do I require this list, if I can tell all I need form json...

Comment: Yeah, you're not actually saving resources that way... I guess _put_ing the whole object is out of the question. A custom model binder is all I can think of....

Comment: @AndreiV It is not out of the question. But it does not meet the requirements. Only properties changed on the client has to be changed in the database. Not changed values has to be preserved. If we are putting the whole object we overwrite everything - this has to be avoided. Saving resources is not the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: If the whole object is being sent to the server, only those _targeted properties_ will differ from what's in the database. The other properties will be "overwritten", but with the same values. Can't say I see a straight forward solution...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80704/discussion-between-zespri-and-andrei-v).

Comment: Why don't you create overloads, each accepting only the relevant parameters for each request?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov there are about a dozen properties. We would like to communicate all the changes in a single call.

Comment: @zespri You can decide on default values that indicate "I haven't changed".

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, you know what. That might just be workable. Although we need to agree on that value for each type (like `int.MaxValue`, `new Guid("ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff")`, `DateTime.MaxValue` etc. I'll think about it.) Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using dynamic proxy for the properties, so that I could mark the properties written by `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` as "dirty".  I used slightly modified [yappi](http://yappi.codeplex.com/) (did not really have to modify it, just wanted to - mentioning this if the code below does not exactly match yappi samples/API). I'm guessing you can use your favourite dynamic proxy library. Just for fun I tried to port it to [NProxy.Core](https://github.com/mtamme/NProxy) but that did not work because for some reason json.net refused to write into proxies that `NProxy.Core` generated.

So it works like this. We have a base class along these lines:

```
public class DirtyPropertiesBase
{
    ...

    // most of these come from Yappi
    public static class Create<TConcept> where TConcept : DirtyPropertiesBase
    {
        public static readonly Type Type =PropertyProxy.ConstructType<TConcept, PropertyMap<TConcept>>(new Type[0], true);
        public static Func<TConcept> New = Constructor.Compile<Func<TConcept>>(Type);
    }

    private readonly List<string> _dirtyList = new List<string>();

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (!_dirtyList.Contains(name))
        {
            _dirtyList.Add(name);
        }
    }
    public bool IsPropertyDirty(string name)
    {
        return _dirtyList.Contains(name);
    }

    ...
    // some more Yappi specific code that calls OnPropertyChanged
    // when a property setter is called
}
```

Somewhere in the proxy implementation we call `OnPropertyChanged` so that we remember which properties were written to.

Then we have our custom `JsonCreationConverter`:

```
class MyJsonCreationConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<DirtyPropertiesBase>> ContructorCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<DirtyPropertiesBase>>();
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("MyJsonCreationConverter should only be used while deserializing.");
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Func<DirtyPropertiesBase> constructor = ContructorCache.GetOrAdd(objectType, x =>
            (Func<DirtyPropertiesBase>)typeof(DirtyPropertiesBase.Create<>).MakeGenericType(objectType).GetField("New").GetValue(null));

        DirtyPropertiesBase value = constructor();
        serializer.Populate(reader, value);
        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof (DirtyPropertiesBase).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

The idea here, is as `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` converts incoming json, we substitute the initial empty object to be the proxy that we defined earlier.

We register this converter in WebApiConfig.cs like this

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyJsonCreationConverter());
```

Now when our model is populated from json in place of each object derived from `DirtyPropertiesBase` there will be a proxy with properly populated `_dirtyList` collection. Now we only need to map each of these models back to EF entity. This is simple enough with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). We register each model like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Model, Entity>().ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(z => ((Model)z.Parent.SourceValue).IsPropertyDirty(z.MemberName)));
```

And then you have your usual mapping code:

```
Entity current = _db.Entity.Single(x => x.Id == Id);
Mapper.Map(update, current);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

That will make sure that only Dirty properties are updated.

Comment: Where are you adding this line of code? Mapper.CreateMap<Model, Entity>().ForAllMembers(x => x.Condition(z => ((Model)z.Parent.SourceValue).IsPropertyDirty(z.MemberName)));

Comment: @cal5barton on start-up

Answer (score 2):

Whilst introduced for OData services, you could try using [`System.Web.Http.OData.Delta<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890572%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). This allows for partial updates of entities.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/easy-asp-net-web-api-resource-updates-with-delta/) for a good discussion on using `Delta<T>`. Essentially it boils down to defining `Put` and `Patch` methods such as:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    // Other actions omitted…

    [AcceptVerbs("Patch")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch(int key, Delta<Item> model)
    {
        var entity = _items.FindAsync(o => o.Id == key);

        if (entity == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        model.Patch(entity);

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(int key, Delta<Item> model)
    {
        var entity = _items.FindAsync(o => o.Id == key);

        if (entity == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        model.Put(entity);

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
}
```

Here a request to `Put` will update the entire model, whereas a request to `Patch` will only partially update the model (using only the properties passed by the client).

Comment: Yep, I've seen this. In my case the `Item` is not a EF entity and it's a complex nested type. I was not able to get `Delta` working properly on it. In particular `model.Patch(entity)` would not work because model and entity are of different types.

Comment: Also all models inside the outer model do not get populated at all. Only immediate simple properties of outermost model is populated. All the second level models always contain `null`.

Comment: Ex: `class TaskData{ public IList<User> AssignedUsers {get; set;} public IList<Product> Products {get; set;} public Task Task {get; set}}` And then `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put(Delta<TaskData>[] model)` Neither `AssignedUsers` and `Products` nor `Task` properties get populated.

Comment: @zespri OK, thanks for the additional information. I am suprised that `Delta<T>` doesn't work with nested properties however. Anyway, it wasn't clear from your question that you needed to support nested properties like the example in your previous comment (the `Item` object in your question only show two primitive type properties). Perhaps you could update your question to include a more complete example. I will leave this question here for other users who might only need support for simple (i.e. not nested) models.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I expressed that idea with `With Sql Server and EF in the back-end that leads to several different (and sometimes unrelated) entities are contained within single json.` Perhaps an example of that would draw more attention to this statement. Let me add it.

Comment: It probably would work with nested properties if these were true EF entities. By looking at WebApi OData code we can see that there is indeed special treatment for EDM collections. How exactly it works though I do not know.

Comment: @zespri Apologies for that - I didn't see that comment in your update. I don't think there should be any difference between using `Delta` with an Entity Framework model or a POCO: OData, and `Delta`, do not know anything about Entity Framework. It might be that `Delta` just doesn't support all the types that it should. There are a few related questions suggesting this. See, for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/14294136/623518 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14506353/623518

Comment: Apparently [this](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/DeltaJsonDeserialization/DeltaJsonDeserialization.Server/DeltaContractResolver.cs) might help with the problem. I'll see if I can make it work later if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is a persistence issue, not a model binder issue.

Your API is being provided a null value for a given property, therefore the binder is honouring it.

Perhaps in persistence you can advise whichever framework you're using to ignore null entries (I assume you're passing up nullable int?s instead of just ints)

Comment: Nope, this is not the case. On persistence level for some fields `null` is a valid value. So it would be nice to tell the difference between a null value and not provided value. In your example, ignoring null entry won't work because if a null value is provided with json I *want* to write it. I only want to ignore if it is not provided. And when json is converted to instance of a model class this information about presence is already lost.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using this pattern.

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Item value)
    {
        if (value.NameSpecified)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

public class Item
{
    internal bool NameSpecified = false;
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            NameSpecified = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The binder does not set the property in both cases when it's null and when it's not specified. So it does not help distinguishing between these two cases.

Comment: Are you sure? It helps me to distinguishing between the two cases. If I post { "ID": null } then IDSpecified is true and if I post { } it's false. Are you using .net core? (I'm not)

Comment: Of course I'm sure. I spent several days may be even couple of weeks resolving this particular issue and trying stuff out in different combinations. I'm not saying that you are not seeing what you seeing, I'm sure you are, but you don't have the same "givens" I had. The tech stack I was using and the concrete examples are all given in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Tell you what, how about you make a minimal repro of your case, upload it to github and post a link here. Then I'll be able to have a look, to see what's different. I can confirm that I was not using .net core.

Comment: I only used the code above in a web api project (I'm using vs2017), create a new web api project and paste in that code in the valuecontroller and try it out.